# Detect And Show Sent Received Wireless Activity

Tags: delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7.  Can anyone help me to retrieve the sent/received stats of a data connection, like the below picture?

[image: Detect And Show Sent Received Wireless Activity]

I would like to display this info in a `TEdit`.

I've tried the following code, but it only works for RAS connections, not for NDIS connections.

```
begin
  newname := MagRasCon.GetConnection;
  if newname = '' then
  begin
    if ConnHandle = 0 then Exit;
    ConnHandle := 0;
    Exit;
  end;

  if ConnHandle <> MagRasCon.CurRASConn then begin
    ConnHandle := MagRasCon.CurRASConn ;
    ConnName := MagRasCon.CurConnName ;
    MagRasPer.ResetPerfStats ;

    if MagRasOSVersion >= OSW2K then 
      MagRasPer.PerfRasConn [1] := ConnHandle ;
    LastXmit := MagRasPer.PerfXmitCur [0] ;
    LastRecv := MagRasPer.PerfRecvCur [0] ;
    LastTime := GetTickCount ;
    lblTotalUP.Caption := '0'; lblTotalDL.Caption := '0';
  end ;

  MagRasCon.CurrentStatusEx (ConnHandle, 0) ;

  if (MagRasCon.ConnectState = RASCS_Connected) then begin
    MagRasPer.GetPerfStats ;
    curxmit := MagRasPer.PerfXmitCur[0] - LastXmit ;
    currecv := MagRasPer.PerfRecvCur[0] - LastRecv ;
    LastXmit := MagRasPer.PerfXmitCur[0] ;
    LastRecv := MagRasPer.PerfRecvCur[0] ;
    LastTime := GetTickCount ;

    //Received Sent Data Connection
    edtSpeedUP.Text := LastXmit;
    edtSpeedDL.Text := LastRecv;
```

Can I still use code like this, or do I have to detect NDIS stats another way?

Comment: Can you format your code so it is readable. Can you also describe how your debugging went.

Comment: thank you for edited my post,, idk what you mean to